# Does CYGWIN need to be in my main OS drive?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I have a main SSD drive for my OS and most my programs (which is getting low on memory 65gb used of 75gb)
`C:\\`

I then have a large drive I use for my data (music, video, photos, and all my code files)
`E:\\`

Now I also run my Dev server with XAMPP (LAMP stack) on Windows 7 on this data drive instead of on my C SSD.

So I just installed CYGWIN to `C:\\cygwin`

I would prefer to put Cygwin on my E drive but I'm not sure if I should or not.  The reason I was considering changing it from ym OS drive to my data drive with server is because the server is on that drive with Apache and PHP and all that related stuff.

Does it really matter though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cygwin can be moved to another drive. You need to use regedit to update the cygwin's artificial "mountpoints" - the registry entries that tell cygwin that "/usr/bin" is really "C:\cygwin\bin", etc.

Similarly, it can be moved to a different directory, for example E:\Utils\Cygwin.